# JavaScript yearly scheduler library

Tags: library, javascript, scheduling, planning

I'm looking for a JavaScript library that allows me to create a scheduler where each main column represent a month, and each "secondary" column represent half of a month.

This image is an example of what I would like to create.

[image]

Each row represent a "place" like a classroom, and 2 events can also is located on the same classroom and month (like blue and red on the example)

I've already seen Kendo Scheduler and FullCalendar, but it unfortunately not allows to split each month in half month...

I also need the event drag and drop feature, someone know a library like the above described?